# I have a String with numeric and characters, and i want to separate

Tags: java, android, regex

I need only text
I used this method but is not work

```
    String zipCode = 325 55 NewYork; 

 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a-zA-Z_0-9]");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(zipCode);
 if(m.matches())
 {
     String s = m.group(1); 
 }
```

Comment: what is not working? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: will there be space after number each time?

Comment: Please clear up your question before it gets closed

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
String zipCode = "411 14 Göteborg";

String extractedString = zipCode .replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();

Log.d("Home", "ExtractedString : " + extractedString);
```

**Output**

```
10-05 08:06:35.137: D/Home(9504): ExtractedString : Göteborg
```

Comment: Did you understand what he wants? How are you sure he wants the city name when the variable is called zipCode? It is really confusing what he wants.

Comment: @AdelBoutros what he wants is he want to fetch out city name from string. he doesn't want pin code and extra text

Comment: Not really, If you check the javadoc for `m.group(1)` "**Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one**"

So he wants the first group of the matching for the regular expression containing even numbers  `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a-zA-Z_0-9]")`. So what I understand from the code is that he wants the first number part `411`